# Should votes be reset when making substantial edits to community ads?

Tags: discussion, community-ads-meta

It seems that votes are kept when editing existing community ad submissions. For example, in [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1107/revisions) case, I would vote for the first version, but not the later ones, and yet the votes are kept. Even if the actual meaning is the same, the formatting and presentation matters.

What should be done about such situations? Should votes be reset if major changes are made to the ads that are presented? Should making major changes to them be disallowed altogether?

Answer (score 6):

I think the underlying issue that you have identified can be addressed more expediently by rolling back the subsequent edits to the version that the community actually upvoted above the necessary threshold.

It does seem a breach of faith, if not of the actual policy which doesn't explicitly prevent this behaviour, to substitute another image(s) once the ad has been accepted. These new images have not been explicitly endorsed by the community and therefore lack the legitimacy of the original.

Even if, as in the case you link to, the images are part of the same branding portfolio, allowing this undermines the concept of the vote and is not a practice that should be encouraged.

I have taken the liberty of reverting to the original logo.